# TinyMCE - Creating anchor tags with empty / no href

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce

I'm trying to create an anchor tag using the TinyMCE editor that has a title tag but with either an empty href attribute or no href attribute at all. I'm using the title tag to create a tooltip on hover.

So for example it outputs:

```
<a title="Tooltip info here">Hover over me</a>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried it and does it work? You haven't indicated if it's working or not

Comment: If I leave the Link URL field empty, it will not add a link in TinyMCE, I need the href of the anchor creating to either be empty or not exist, so when clicked nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Tooltip info here">Hover over me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create an own plugin for that.
You may modify the anchor plugin shipped with tinymce for that.
All you need to do is to add a href tag.